# python:'map' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7, numpy

"Contestant who earns a score equal to or greater than the k-th place finisher's score will advance to the next round, as long as the contestant earns a positive score..." — an excerpt from contest rules.

A total of n participants took part in the contest ( n ≥ k), and you already know their scores. Calculate how many participants will advance to the next round.

**Input**

The first line of the input contains two integers n and k (1 ≤ k ≤ n ≤ 50) separated by a single space.

The second line contains n space-separated integers a 1, a 2, ..., a n (0 ≤ a i ≤ 100), where a i is the score earned by the participant who got the i-th place. The given sequence is non-increasing (that is, for all i from 1 to n - 1 the following condition is fulfilled: a i ≥ a i + 1).
Output

**Output**
the number of participants who advance to the next round.

```
n,k=map(int,input().split())
lst=map(int,input().split())
count=0
for i in lst:
   if i>0 and i>=lst[k-1] :
        count+=1
print(count)
```

**My Output**

```
if i>0 and i>=lst[k-1] :
TypeError: 'map' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: try `n,k = list(map(int,input().split()))` and similar for `lst`.

Comment: In Python 3 `map` returns a generator and not a list. Genrators can not be indexed but you can just run it through `list()` to get a list.